# OpenCV - Video doesn't play after saving in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I tried to save a video after it changes resolution to 300x300 on Python, but my video can't play after saving with

```
0xc10100be error: "This file isn't playable. That might be because the file type is unsupported, the file extension is incorrect, or the file is corrupt."
```

Here is my program:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("F:\\mi\\Camera\\2b7d9eccaddffffe3c9ba70b7fe6c12e(0).mp4")
cv2.namedWindow("vid1", 0)
cv2.resizeWindow("vid1", 300,300)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (300,300))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('vid1',frame)
    out.write(frame)                            
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a video file to test this with?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g3egtiuohll856x/screen_recorder_video_2020_03_6_06_43_46.mp4?dl=0

Comment: that's a video that I tested

Answer (score 3):

after asking my teacher about this problem, He fixed my program:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("F:\\mi\\Camera\\2b7d9eccaddffffe3c9ba70b7fe6c12e(0).mp4")
cv2.namedWindow('frame',0)
cv2.resizeWindow('frame',300,300)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (300,300))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        vidout=cv2.resize(frame,(300,300)) #create vidout funct. with res=300x300
        out.write(vidout) #write frames of vidout function
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks for your attention about my question!

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: He said I should add a resize 300x300 resolution function so that my computer can understand I'm working with 300x300 video resolution.

Comment: @AMC Are you learning/working about OpenCV? Do you have a Facebook account? I have just learned about OpenCV recently so that I want to add some friends to exchange OpenCV regularly. :D

Comment: _Are you learning/working about OpenCV?_ No, sorry. I don't think I would be of much help.

Answer (score 0):

I appears to me that you're not doing anything with "out".

You should add:

```
out.write(frame)
```

inside the loop.

Comment: @DucPhanDoan Why was this accepted as the answer? Did it fix the issue or not?

Comment: @AMC not yet bro 